# Error Jsp Adding Subtracting Numbers

Tags: java, html, jsp

this web app is a simple calculator that adds and subtracts. my problem is that the add and the subtract buttons don't work. before i tried using switch statement but now i am using an if statement but still doesn't work

```
   <%
    String name = (String) session.getAttribute("name");
    if (name==null) {
            name = request.getParameter("name");
            if (name!=null) session.setAttribute("name",name);
    }

    String sum = (String) session.getAttribute("sum");
    if (sum==null) {
            sum = "0";
            session.setAttribute("sum",sum);
    }
    int isum = Integer.parseInt(sum);

    String number = request.getParameter("number");
    if (number==null) number = "0";
    int inumber = Integer.parseInt(number);
    if(request.getParameter("add") != null){ 
    isum += inumber;
    session.setAttribute("sum",""+isum);
    }
    if(request.getParameter("subtract") != null){
    isum += inumber;
    session.setAttribute("sum",""+isum);
    }
    %>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>Adding Machine</title>
    </head>
    <body>
            <form method='get' action='adder.jsp'>
    <%
    if (name==null) {
    %>
                    <p>
                            Name: <input type='text' name='name' id='name'>
                    </p>
                    <p>
                            <input type='submit' name='submit' id='submit' value='signin'>
                    </p>
    <%
    } else {
    %>
                    <p>Welcome, <%=name%>!</p>
                    <p>Current sum is: <%=isum%></p>
                    <p>
                            Number to add: <input type='text' name='number' id='number' value='add'>
                    </p>
                    <p>
                         <input type='submit' name='submit' id='submit' value='add'>
                    </p>
                    <p>
                          <input type='submit' name='submit' id='submit' value='subtract'>
                    </p>
    <%
    }
    %>
            </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: is this the entire jsp?  Please mark line 19 for us, as it is more beneficial.

Answer (score 1):

replace your single quotes with double in switch

Answer (score 1):

So an invalid character constant happens if you try to assign something to a char / Character that has a length greater than 1 (one) .  You need to place  `case 'add':` with `case "add":`  repeat for all other attributes in the switch statement.

Comment: thank you but know i get more errors :  "18 in the jsp file: /adder.jsp opchar cannot be resolved " and "An error occurred at line: 52 in the jsp file: /adder.jsp opchar cannot be resolved" i know i need to initialize opchar but dont know how